# Trouble with UIWebView: Unwanted Horizontal Scroll Bars

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I'm loading some simple local HTML that is all text, nothing fancy, into a UIWebView. Before iOS 4.1 it displays fine without my doing anything. From 4.2 on, the same HTML fills a window that is larger than the screen (portrait layout) and so the horizontal bar appear and scrolling is required to see the whole page.

Has anyone else had this problem and if so what did you do to fix it?

I've done everything I can think of which includes:
- setting the body dimension in the css.
- using the viewport meta tag to set the content to device-width (this just shrunk the size of the text but the window stayed the same size (i.e. too big).
- setting the frame and/or bounds of the webview.
- setting scale to fit on the webview.

Nothing has worked. The web view display area is still about twice as wide as the screen.

Baffled!

Comment: Well, I found the problem. The right answer is to use the viewport meta tag:
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-size" />

The this works just fine if loading the html page using the webview loadRequest method. However, it does not work if loading your html with the loadHTMLString method. I figure this has got to be a bug.

Incidentally, I'm was using the loadHTMLString method because I wanted to make some changes to the HTML before loading it.

Comment: Okaaay, so that wasn't quite it either. I was pre-loading the html into a web view and holding that in an instance variable for display at a later time. Under these conditions, the viewport tag doesn't work. The viewport tag is correctly interpreted if the web view is built and displayed on demand via the loadView method.